# O que fazer para salvar registro no meu banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá

Tenho o seguinte código e as informações não salvam no meu banco de dados.
Alguém pode me ajudar? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username='root';
$password=null;
$dbname='task3';

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
// verifica a conexao
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Erro ao conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
        


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $Team=$_POST['Team_Name'];
        $Player1=$_POST['Player1'];
        $Player2=$_POST['Player2'];
        $Player3=$_POST['Player3'];
        $Player4=$_POST['Player4'];
        $Player5=$_POST['Player5'];
        $Age1=$_POST['Age1'];
        $Age2=$_POST['Age2'];
        $Age3=$_POST['Age3'];
        $Age4=$_POST['Age4'];
        $Age5=$_POST['Age5'];
        $Email=$_POST['Email'];
        $register_query = "INSERT INTO `tabela`(`id`, `Team Name 1`, `Team Name 2`, `Team Name 3`, `Team Name 4`, `Team Name 5`, `Age Player 1`, `Age Player 2`, `Age Player 3`, `Age Player 4`, `Age Player 5`, `Team Email`) VALUES ('$Team', '$Player1', '$Player2', '$Player3', '$Player4', '$Player5', '$Age1', '$Age2', '$Age3', '$Age4', '$Age5', '$Email')";
    


try{
$register_result = mysqli_query($conn, $register_query);
if($register_result){
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0){
echo("registration successful");
}else{
echo("error in registration");
}
 
}
}catch(Exception $ex){
echo("error".$ex->getMessage());
}
}
 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>REgistrar</title>

</head>

<body>
<h1> Cadastrar Utilizador </h1>
<form name="signup" method="POST" action="ultima_tentativa.php"> 
<label>Team Name</label>
<input type="text" name="Team_Name" placeholder="Team Name"><br><br>

<label>Player 1</label>
<input type="text" name="Player1" placeholder="Player 1"><br><br>

<label>Player 2:</label>
<input type="text" name="Player2" placeholder="Player 2"><br><br>

<label>Player 3:</label>
<input type="text" name="Player3" placeholder="Player 3"><br><br>

<label>Player 4:</label>
<input type="text" name="Player4" placeholder="Player 4"><br><br>

<label>Player 5:</label>
<input type="text" name="Player5" placeholder="Player 5"><br><br>

<label>Age Player 1:</label>
<input type="int" name="Age1" placeholder="Age Player 1"><br><br>

<label>Age Player 2:</label>
<input type="int" name="Age2" placeholder="Age Player 2"><br><br>

<label>Age Player 3:</label>
<input type="int" name="Age3" placeholder="Age Player 3"><br><br>

<label>Age Player 4:</label>
<input type="int" name="Age4" placeholder="Age Player 4"><br><br>

<label>Age Player 5:</label>
<input type="int" name="Age5" placeholder="Age Player 5"><br><br>

<label>Team Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email Team"><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: coloque um `mysqli_error` apos a execução da query e veja se retorna algo.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php7/default.asp

Comment: Os campos não podem ter espaços no INSERT. Vc colocou isso apenas para exemplificar ou esse é o código real?

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Vejo que no seu insert, suas colunas `id`, `Team Name 1`, `Team Name 2` e etc... estão com espaços. Confirma na sua tabela os nomes das colunas.

Outra coisa, você está recebendo na variaval $Team=$_POST['Team_Name']; e salvando ela na coluna "id" que provavelmente seja Integer.

Post o erro exato que ocorre na hora de fazer o insert, assim ficara mais facil ajudar.